# Is it possible to use the Idris FFI as an Effect?

Tags: idris

Suppose I have a function of type `Eff () [STDIO]` in Idris. This lets you do basic console I/O operations, but does not allow you to use Idris' foreign function interface.

Is there an effect in idris that lets you do this, or some other way to get around this problem? I don't want to use `IO` like in [this example](https://github.com/reynir/idris-ffi-example), as I'd like to be able to mix the FFI with other effects. So, if I wanted to use the FFI and a state effect, for example, I'd like to be able to use the type: `Eff () [FFI,State Int]`. Is this possible in the current implementation of Idris?